# Choose between class level alignment and variable level alignment

Tags: c++, memory-alignment

Say I have a member variable `aligned_` in class `A` that should be 64-byte aligned

```
class A {
    int val1_;
    int val2_;
    ....
    __m256i aligned_;
};
```

I can do either

```
class alignas(64) A {
    __m256i aligned_;
    int val1_;
...
```

or

```
alignas(64) __m256i aligned_;
```

I am struggling with which one is better. So far I have these conclusions:

1. Using class level alignment saves spaces as all variables are adjacent to each other, but I have to put the aligned variable as the first member, which disturbing my coding habit of putting related member variables together.
2. Using variable level alignment solves the problems mentioned in 1, but needs extra space before the variable to be aligned. This makes class A taking more space than needed

I would like to have your advice on this topic. Thanks!

Comment: Oh sorry for the confusion. The variable "aligned_" in my program is actually an AVX2 type "__m256i". I need it to be aligned, otherwise assigning value to it may cause SEG FAULT. I have updated my question.

Comment: I would definitely keep the `alignas` close to the member variable that needs the alignment, however, putting it at the start would probably be best. If it makes your code difficult to read, you'll only waste a few bytes.